# Python Django NoReverseMatch using URL in template

Tags: python, django, url

I know that this is a common issues, but none of the answers which I found here helped me out.
I cannot figure out what is wrong here (Yes I tried with '' and without them in url)

Here's what I got so far

template:

```
<html>
<body>
<div> Link here </div> <a href="{% url 'index' %}">{{ formText }}</a>
</body>
</html>
```

url(own config)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from metadaten import views

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

root url:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^metadaten/', include('metadaten.urls', namespace='metadaten')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from metadaten.models import Title
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'metadaten/index.html', {'formText' : 'foo'})
```

error message:

```
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Any suggestions why I'm not able to build a simple href using {% url %} ?

please don't blame me if this question might be easy to figure out :(

Comment: just `{% url 'index' %}`  should work

Comment: no sorry does not work

Comment: also, if you are using django pre-1.5, you should not use `'index'` - It would be `{% url index %}`

Comment: no I'm not using pre-1.5 also tried this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a namespace with `metadaten`.  You'll want to use `{% url 'metadaten:index' %}`.

Look at the last example for the [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: great, could you also try to tell me why {% url 'metadaten:index' formText %} does not work??

Comment: `metadaten:index` doesn't expect a parameter.  If you want to include a parameter, you need to include it on the url pattern and in your index function in views.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls.